# Haskell: Why this would lead to empty list exception?

Tags: list, exception, haskell, side-effects

I am currently working on Project Euler for fun, and use Haskell for practicing. However, I encountered a problem, and I cannot seem to produce a smaller example, so here are the codes (for project euler 232):

```
buildNum (x, y) = multNum x y 1 []
  where multNum num mul exp s = if (num > 10 ^ 100) then s else multNum nNum mul nexp ns
          where next = (num * mul) `div` exp
                ns = num:s
                top = next `mod` 10
                nexp = exp * 10
                nNum = num + nexp * top

sumBuild (x, y) = (head (buildNum (x, y))) * length (buildNum (x, y))
```

Please ignore bad style here:)

If I load this and run sumBuild(7, 5) here, I would get a exception:

```
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

But if I change sumBuild to:

```
sumBuild (x, y) = head (buildNum (x, y))
```

or

```
sumBuild (x, y) = length (buildNum (x, y))
```

then it runs fine.

This is really confusing for me, since there is no side effect and two runs produce different results (at least it seems to be such a case). What is the problem here?

If someone could edit this program into a minimum working example, then I am really grateful!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the hint:

```
> :t sumBuild
sumBuild :: (Int, Int) -> Int
> let a = 7 :: Int
> a > 10^100
True
```

As a suggestion try always explicitly state types of top level declarations. This helps to avoid such bugs.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that by multiplying with the result of `length`, which is an `Int`, you force all the calculations to be done with the machine-sized `Int` type, leading to overflows. When you remove that, the default arbitrary-sized `Integer` type is used instead.

If you add a type signature and a `fromIntegral` to force the calculations to be done with `Integer`, everything works as expected.

```
buildNum :: (Integer, Integer) -> [Integer]
buildNum (x, y) = -- same as before

sumBuild :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
sumBuild (x, y) = (head (buildNum (x, y))) * fromIntegral (length (buildNum (x, y)))
```